# php dictionary-style array and sort by specific key name

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a foreach construct:

```
foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
    if($value && $value > 0){ // ensure we have a positive amount
        $composite = explode("-", Replace($name, "ScheduleID_", ""));
        $scheduleID = $composite[0];
        $thisUserID = $composite[1];
        $payPalEmail = $composite[2];
        $amount = $value;

        $counter++;
        $sum += $value;
    }
}
```

I'm getting correct values in all my variables. Inside the foreach I need to construct an array containing these 4 values:

1. $scheduleID
2. $thisUserID
3. $payPalEmail
4. $amount

...and then sort the array by $thisUserID. And then I need to know how to build the foreach to correctly iterate the new array and grab each of my values.

**IMPORTANT: Every $scheduleID will be unique, but the other 3 values will sometimes repeat.**

I was thinking something like this, but can't get it to work right:

```
$object["ScheduleID"] = $scheduleID 
$object["UserID"] = $thisUserID 
$object["PayPalEmail"] = $payPalEmail 
$object["Amount"] = $amount
```

(and then perform the sort on $object["UserID"]) - I have tried different sort schemes from stackoverflow and php docs, but I must be doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can just prepare array in foreach like this:

```
foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
    if($value && $value > 0){ // ensure we have a positive amount
        $composite = explode("-", Replace($name, "ScheduleID_", ""));
        $objects[$composite[0]] = array( 
           'UserID' => $composite[1],
           'payPalEmail' => $composite[2]
        );
        $amount = $value;

        $counter++;
        $sum += $value;
    }
}
ksort($objects);
```

Then after foreach You can sort array by ksort.

Comment: Toorion, I need more detail. It's the ksort that hasn't been working for me. Please give exact code of the ksort and the new foreach. Thx.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but it's still not there yet. I tried the following: foreach($objects as $name => $value ) {
 foreach($value as $name2 => $value2 ) {
  writeme("$name2 = $value2");
 }
} -- it doesn't sort by UserID, which is the requirement. And in your ksort($objects) you're not telling it to sort by UserID. Please tell me what the correct ksort should be. Thanks.

Comment: No, UserID repeates sometimes, but it must be sorted by that. I have it working now, had to use pieces of your answer and pieces of another post. How can I post the final solution but still give you points? Can I send you the final code, you post it, and I accept your answer? I just edited your answer. Can you somehow accept it?